# Trigger a parallel node progress bar on spawn sync child process

Tags: node.js, npm, progress, child-process, spawn

I am basically trying to build my own wrapper around `npm install package` functionality.

I have successfully written the install function wrapper but now I want to trigger a progress bar when I am sync spawning a child process which basically installs `npm modules`, here is my code below

```
const spawn = require('cross-spawn');
const ProgressBar = require('progress');
const chalk = require('chalk');

public static installPkgs =
  (des: any, packages: string[], opts: any) => {
    const args: string[] = [];
    if (opts.save) {
      args.push('-S');
    }
    if (opts.saveDev) {
      args.push('-D');
    }
    if (opts.global) {
      args.push('-g');
    }
    const cliArgs: string[] = ['i'].concat(args, packages);

    if (typeof des === 'string') {
      process.stdout.write('\n' + chalk.yellow(des) + '\n');
    } else {
      process.stdout.write('');
    }

    const barOpts =  { 
                      width: 20, 
                      total: packages.length, 
                      clear: true
                     };

    const bar = new ProgressBar(' uploading [:bar] :percent :etas', barOpts);

    bar.tick(0);

    const bat = spawn.sync('npm', cliArgs, {stdio:'pipe'});

    bar.tick(bat.stdout.toString().length);
}
```

Now my problems are -

- I am not sure whether to use `packages.length` for the **total** property of progress bar tick completion
- Since the spawning is happening in synchronous way, the progress bar is triggered after that process how can I trigger it as soon as the npm modules are being downloaded?

Please help me guide in the right direction on how to achieve the above!

Comment: Why not use `yarn` instead? Just curious

Comment: That is a work around just to see the yarn's neat progress bar but I would like to generate it programmatically!

Comment: First of all, spawn.sync is incompatible with what you're trying to do... because it's synchronous! bar.tick won't be triggered before the command is completed. Another thing is that packages.length doesn't make sense for npm, it installs them simultaneously. You could do that by spawning npm `packages.length ` times but this would be very inefficient. Yet another thing is that NPM doesn't seem to output progress information in a way that could be easily read from stdout, but it outputs progress bar. I'd suggest to re-ask how to read progress bar changes from `spawn('npm')` streams.